# Can multiple classes inherit from a single instance of a base class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I make use of a templated class so that I only have to maintain a single class which can handle all the types I need (could be hundreds). Here's the functor for that class where everything is done.

```
template <class T>
void SomeClass<T>::operator()()
{
    Connection *conn = getConn();

    while (true) {
        auto data = conn->poll(ms));

        T t();
        do_something_with(t, data);
    }
}
```

And I execute each one in a thread.

```
SomeClass<MyObj1> obj1();
SomeClass<MyObj2> obj2();
// ...
SomeClass<MyObj99> obj99();
SomeClass<MyObj100> obj100();

std::thread t1(obj1);
std::thread t2(obj2);
// ...
std::thread t99(obj99);
std::thread t100(obj100);
```

As one can see, that's a lot of while loops running in the background.

Is there a solution/pattern to doing something like this where I can keep the templated classfixing typo, but somehow remove/merge the while loops in operator()() into a single while loop? The reason for removing all the while loops would be to reduce resources so that I can run this on small devices.

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow make it so that multiple SomeClass's can inherit from a single instance of a base class that actually runs a single main loop. Though I can't imagine what that would look like.

**Update:**
One thing I should add is that, the connection and receiving of data stays around for the life of the program.

Comment: Nobody holds you off from implementing an event queue with dispatch. Then you could bundle several SomeClass objects per thread. The question is also, what does the conn.poll do? Does it really poll? The right mechanism to wait for several resources (like network sockets) at once is `select()`. Can you use it for your scenario as well?

Comment: Note that `Connection conn();` declares a function named `conn` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `Connection`.  This should probably be `Connection conn;`.

Comment: I just put Connection in as an example and changed that part of it.

Comment: Why do you need templates for this question? With the information currently given, it looks like you would face the same issue if you just had multiple objects of the same `SomeClass` type. I guess try dividing your current problem into two? First, how to use a single `while` loop for multiple objects. Second, how to have a single `while` loop do something with different types.

Comment: @ypnos - Event queue w/ dispatch, very interesting.

Comment: `Can multiple classes inherit from a single instance of a base class?` Yes. This is called virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of would be to have some queue and you would add the a pointer (this) of the object into that queue.

Otherwise, I don't think you can have some sort of static parent class like you are asking.